# remove class add class not working

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

i have created two separate classes for li which contains up & down arrows background image.

html

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="main">Menu 1
<ul class="submenu">
<li class="submenu_item">Sub menu 1</li>
<li class="submenu_item">Sub menu 2</li>
<li class="submenu_item">Sub menu 3</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="main">Menu 2
<ul class="submenu">
<li class="submenu_item">Sub menu 1</li>
<li class="submenu_item">Sub menu 2</li>
<li class="submenu_item">Sub menu 3</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
li.main
{display:block;
background:#06C url(insert.png) top right no-repeat;
margin-top:1%;
}

.remove
{display:block;
background:#06C url(remove.GIF) top right no-repeat;
margin-top:1%;
}
```

script

```
$(".main:eq(0)").click(function () {
    $(".submenu:eq(0)").slideToggle(400);
    $(this).toggleClass("main remove");
    $(".submenu:eq(1)").slideUp(400);
});

$(".main:eq(1)").click(function () {
    $(".submenu:eq(1)").slideToggle(400);
    $(this).toggleClass("main remove");
    $(".submenu:eq(0)").slideUp(400);
});
```

when i clicked on the li i needed the class will change but if i again click on menu1 menu 2 
class also has to be changed.

Comment: when someone clicked on menu 2, menu 1 class will change to main,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it act like an accordion, you can do like this:

```
$('.main').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("main remove").find('.submenu').slideToggle(400);
    $(this).closest('li').siblings('.main').find('.submenu').slideUp(400);
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C756x/1/)**

---

I think you don't need to slideUp the other `.main` when one `.main` clicked, so just use:

```
$('.main').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("main remove").find('.submenu').slideToggle(400);
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C756x/2/)**

Comment: thanks @Felix but this is not changing the background image if i click on menu 2

Comment: @AtalShrivastava I'm not sure why since I can see the background-url in my demo has been changed. Check my update as well

Comment: that will change if you click on the same menu again, but what i have done if menu 1 is open and someone click on menu 2 it will close menu 1 & open menu 2. so the arrows also has to changed while menus opening or closing.

Answer (score 0):

use `:first` or and `.eq()`

```
$(".main").eq(0)
```

and toggle class if you have main on `<li class="main">` only apply `.remove` please change it to other class